# Which ORM do you recommend to use with Node.js and PostgreSQL?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm doing a project where I will need to access PostgreSQL from Node. As I want it to be a more professional thing I want to use an ORM.

What ORM would you recommend ?

I expect that it:

- supports the normal database operations. I have used Hibernate (Java) and Doctrine (PHP). Something like that is OK.
- allows native queries if needed.
- is stable enough so I can have some confidence the project won't be abandoned in a couple months.

But maybe I new to javascript or don't understand the 'js way'. So be free to recommend whatever ORM you like. Just please explain why my expectations aren't realistic in your view (they seem quite basic to me).